# What changed in .net 5 that makes it not throw when changing dictionary values in foreach

Tags: c#, .net-5

In .NET<5 and .NET Core 3.1 the following code

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, int> { { "a", 0 }, { "b", 0 }, { "c", 0 } };
foreach (var k in d.Keys) 
{
   d[k]+=1;
}
```

**throws**

> System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

When targeting .NET 5 the snippet no longer throws.

What has changed?

I failed to find the answer in [Breaking changes in .NET 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/5.0) and [Performance Improvements in .NET 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/performance-improvements-in-net-5/).

Is it something to do with `ref readonly T`?

Comment: I think we should be able to find the answer in the source code to `Dictionary<, >`, starting reading from the `set` accessor of the indexer `public TValue this[TKey key] { /* ... */ }`. There should exist a private field that keeps track on whether the collection was modified or not. If I assign with the setter `d[k] = tmp;` and `k` was previously in the `Dictionary<,>`, does that count as a modification? They must have changed that.

Comment: In the old version, they do `entries[i].value = value; version++; return;` in the branch where we have an update. The `version++` ensures the enumerator will blow up with an exception on the next `MoveNext()` on the enumerator.

Comment: (They also allow it with the value collection, for example `foreach (var v in d.Values) 
    { 
      Console.WriteLine("Top " + v + " " + d["c"]);
      d["c"] += 1;
      Console.WriteLine("Bottom " + v + " " + d["c"]);
    }`. So I guess there is still only one `version` field for both keys and values. Where do I see the new C# source of `public class Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`?)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There was a change to the source code of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` to allow updates of *existing keys* during enumeration. It was commited on April 9, 2020 by Stephen Toub. That commit can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/commit/c007a0d1ced0f3e5f69758f72cdf32a31d983db7#diff-e5e062feb7b078d66f972ed4645eecbe12166633901eccceb847515a7e7d4a28) along with corresponding [PR #34667](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/34667).

The PR is titled "Allow Dictionary overwrites during enumeration" and notes that it fixes [issue #34606](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/34606) "Consider removing `_version++` from overwrites in `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`". The text of that issue, opened by Mr. Toub is as follows:

> We previously removed the  `_version++`  when Remove'ing from a
> dictionary. We should consider doing so as well when just overwriting
> a value for an existing key in the dictionary. This would enable
> update loops that tweak a value in the dictionary without needing to
> resort to convoluted and more expensive measures.

A comment on that issue asks:

> What is the benefit of doing this?

To which Stephen Toub [replied](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/34606#issuecomment-610903250):

> As called out in the original post, fine patterns that are currently throwing today will start working correctly, e.g.
>
> `foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in dict)`
>      `dict[pair.Key] = pair.Value + 1;`

If you look at the `Dictionary<, >` [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/46127eae6eb5a77c2dff8cd533bf8d55f8159d0e/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary.cs), you can see that the `_version` field (which is used to detect modifications) is now only updated under certain conditions and *not* when an existing key is modified.

The area of particular interest is the [`TryInsert`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/46127eae6eb5a77c2dff8cd533bf8d55f8159d0e/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary.cs#L498) method (which is called by the indexer, see below) and its third parameter of type `InsertionBehavior`. When this value is `InsertionBehavior.OverwriteExisting` the versioning field is not updated for an *existing* key.

For example, see this [section of code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/46127eae6eb5a77c2dff8cd533bf8d55f8159d0e/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary.cs#L537,L541) from the *updated* `TryInsert`:

```cs
if (behavior == InsertionBehavior.OverwriteExisting)
{ 
    entries[i].value = value;
    return true;
}
```

*Prior* to the change that section looked like this (code comment mine):

```cs
if (behavior == InsertionBehavior.OverwriteExisting)
{ 
    entries[i].value = value;
    _version++; // <-----
    return true;
}
```

Note that the increment of the `_version` field has been removed, thus allowing modifications during enumeration.

For completeness, the [setter of the indexer](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/46127eae6eb5a77c2dff8cd533bf8d55f8159d0e/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary.cs#L202,%20L206) looks like this. It was not modified by this change, but note the third parameter which influences the above behavior:

```cs
set 
{
    bool modified = TryInsert(key, value, InsertionBehavior.OverwriteExisting);
    Debug.Assert(modified);
}
```

`Remove`'ing from the dictionary no longer impacts enumeration either. That, however, has been around since netcore 3.0 and is appropriately called out in the [documentation of `Remove`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.remove?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_2_Remove__0_#Remarks):

> .NET Core 3.0+ only: this mutating method may be safely called without
> invalidating active enumerators on
> the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` instance. This does not imply thread
> safety.

Despite one developer's insistence in the linked issue that the documentation be updated (and what appears to be an assurance that it *would* be), the docs for the indexer have not yet (2021-04-04) been updated to reflect the current behavior.

Comment: Good find! The change in the `Dictionary.cs` file (the commit link in your answer) is in fact exactly like I expected. I wonder if it would make sense to make a change to `List<>` as well? Namely when you do `list[index] = newvalue;` (i.e. the indexer `set` accessor), this does only overwrite the value in a "slot" that exists already. So this becomes related to [my answer in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41246500) where this aspect of a `List<>` is explained.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen thanks. A lot of digging through the git blame before I realized I could just look at the file history lol

Comment: As of today, to implement the change in `List<>` I am talking about, all it takes is to remove [line 162 in List.cs file](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs#L162). So anyone seeing this can make a pull request and ruin my answer from the other thread (previous comment by me).